# css grid auto-fill direction?

Tags: css, layout, css-grid

maybe this is a strange question. I cannot find any answer in css docs.
Please see this:

[image]

This is something like

```
grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(200px, 1fr));
```

There's an auto-column on the right. Now, what if I'd like to invert the direction of the auto-filling feature? I mean, images on the right, new empty columns on the left? Is it some way possible?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `direction: rtl` and explicity state the order of the child items like follows. You'd need to reset the text direction in the children too. See below.

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  direction: rtl;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(200px, 1fr));
}

.one {
  /* I use negative numbers here so although '-1' is the first item, it appears last but makes it easier to remember */
  order: -1;
}

.two {
  order: -2;
}

.image {
  /* have to reset the text direction here */
  direction: ltr;
  color: #2a7e1f;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class='image one'><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/200" alt="">
    Test 1
  </div>
  <div class='image two'><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/238/200/200" alt="">
    Test 2
  </div>
</div>
```